# parse the part of url and send to function

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a controller called customers and the function called products. I have link like this
http://mysite.com/customers/products/{customernumber}/imagefile.png

I want to have my function get the imagefile.png once my customer put link in the browser on my site.

Howd I do that with cakephp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your action called `products` needs two arguments to deal with that:

```
function products($customernumber, $image) {
    //here you can access these variables and use them for further processing
}
```

I hope this was your problem in this case, please comment if you need help on the "getting the image" case.